# can't get $.getJSON to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm having some trouble with the jquery function getJSON

```
function loadJSON(){
  console.log("loading JSON")
  var jsonFile = themeURL+"/map.json"
  $.getJSON(jsonFile, function(data){
    console.log("loaded JSON")
    $("#infobox").fadeOut(1000)
    info = data
    $("#info rect").on("click", pointClick);
  })
}
```

this doesn't work. it doesn't even get to the console.log("loaded JSON") statement

but then i manually try to do it in the console:

[image: as far as I can see, it goes clean through without any trouble]

can anybody help with this?

Comment: Looks like you're missing quite a few semicolons in there. Aside from that, my guess is that your `jsonFile` URL is improperly formatted. What errors are you seeing in the console?

Comment: To be fair, semicolons are optional. You should absolutely use them, but they are inferred.

Comment: How is "loadJSON" called?

Comment: Are you have any script errors in your console ? is `pointClick` variable defined ?

Comment: Where is `themeURL` defined ?

Comment: There are no errors in the console. the semicolons are optional as said. The loadJSON is called on document ready with loadJSON();. pointClick is a function, not a variable. themeURL is a constant defined outside the function

Comment: Looks like you think `info` (or in other words, the data returned) is available outside the callback. It's not !

Comment: Is it going into the error handler? `$.getJSON(jsonFile,function(){}).error(function(){ console.log(arguments); });`

Comment: @epascarello can't you make and answer? I didn't know how to make errors visible, but when i implemented your code it made the problem obivious. There was a stupid syntax error in my json file, because i'm use to programming in python XD

Comment: Set a breakpoint in the debugger and simply debug your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the success callback is not being hit and the call is 200 from the server, than you have a parsing error that jQuery eats up and does not tell you about.

```
$.getJSON(jsonFile, function(data){
    console.log("loaded JSON")
}).error( function () {
    console.log(arguments);
});
```